# Differential Equation with inverse function $\frac{1-f^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)}{1-x} = 1- \frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}$

Tags: functional-equations

> $$\frac{1-f^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)}{1-x} = 1- \frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}$$

I know $f(x) = ax+b$ is a solution. How can I find other solutions?

Comment: Have you checked if $f(x)=ax+b \  \  \forall \  \ a,b\neq 0$ is a solution? This is the first what I would do if I´m facing this problem.

Comment: Yes. That's a solution. I want to find other solutions. Or prove that is the only solution.

Comment: I have to admit that the solution doesn´t work for me. Maybe I´m wrong, but maybe I´m right. A calculation that shows that $f(x)=ax+b$ is a solution would indicate that you are really interested in that exercise.

Comment: I checked again. That is a solution.

Comment: Yes. That is a critical equation in my research project.

Comment: One idea to start with is to try to simplify it by substituting $x \to f^{-1}(x)$ and using $f^{-1}(x)' = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ to write it on the form $\frac{g(x)-g\left(\frac{x}{g(x)}\right)}{x - \frac{x}{g(x)}} = g'(x)$ where $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. What should do the next step?

Comment: I don't know. My guess would be that linear functions are the only solutions, but this is just a guess. The only thing I can think off is to try to study the function along sequences on the form $x_{n+1} = x_n/g(x_n)$ and somehow try to use this local information to obtain some constraints on the global behavior of your function. It's a very vague idea and don't know if it would work. Hopefully someone will come up with a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment, not an answer, but I'd need the space... Inverse functions are stressful, so you might eliminate yours by 
$$  f^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)  =1 -\left (1- \frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}\right ) (1-x),$$
so that 
$$  \frac{f(x)}{x}   =f\left (1 -\left (1- \frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}\right ) (1-x)\right ),$$
so that
$$
f(x)=xf\left( \frac{f(x)/f’(x)}{ x}+\frac{xf'(x) -f(x)}{f'(x)} \right),$$
manifestly possessing your leading binomial solution. Near the origin, only the leading term in the r.h.side argument is singular.

After doing this, you might well start plugging in series solutions and devising creative coefficient recursions...